Prevent a class from being instantiated as const with build_runner and go_router_builder in flutter
In the following code, I'm defining a StatefulShellRoute with branches:
@TypedStatefulShellRoute<AppShellRouteData>(branches: [
  TypedStatefulShellBranch(
    routes: [
      TypedGoRoute<HomeScreenRoute>(path: '/'),
    ],
  ),
  TypedStatefulShellBranch(
    routes: [
      TypedGoRoute<ScheduleScreenRoute>(path: '/schedule'),
    ],
  ),
  TypedStatefulShellBranch(
    routes: [
      TypedGoRoute<JobsScreenRoute>(path: '/jobs', routes: [
        TypedGoRoute<JobScreenRoute>(path: 'job', name: 'job'),
      ]),
    ],
  ),
  TypedStatefulShellBranch(
    routes: [
      TypedGoRoute<SettingsScreenRoute>(path: '/settings'),
    ],
  ),
])
class AppShellRouteData extends StatefulShellRouteData {
  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state,
      StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell) {
    return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation(navigationShell: navigationShell);
  }
}

I'm using AppShellRouteData to wrap the shell with ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation. The problem is that in the generated file, an extension on AppShellRouteData initialized AppShellRouteData as a constant which throws an error.
extension $AppShellRouteDataExtension on AppShellRouteData {
  static AppShellRouteData _fromState(GoRouterState state) =>
      const AppShellRouteData();
}

How do I fix this?
I have tried defining the extension on my router file without the const expecting it to just replicate it on the generated file.
